# ERROR showing up instead of 0 in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

new to report builder, I'm trying to solve an issue where the grand total in the report is showing #error instead of 0.
[Error in Grand Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k3jq.png)

Here's the expression for the field:

```
=Code.Divide(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!InExtCost.Value, "ClassDesc"), 5), Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!InTranQty.Value, "ClassDesc"),  First(Fields!DecimalsQuantity.Value, "RptParameter")))
```

Divide is the custom code written:

```
Public Function Divide(ByVal dividend As Double, ByVal divisor As Double) As Double
   If IsNothing(divisor) Or divisor = 0 Or IsNothing(dividend) Or dividend = 0 Then
      Return 0
   Else
      Return dividend / divisor
   End If
End Function
```

I've tried using the code to run 0 divide by 1 and 1 divide 0 and both of them shows up 0 in the report preview, I'm expecting it to show up 0 if either dividend or divisor is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are NULL values causing the error.

In any case i created a sample dataset with a mix of values

```
SELECT 50.123456789 AS InExtCost, 10.123456789 As InTranQty   UNION ALL
SELECT 50.123456789 AS InExtCost, 0 As InTranQty   UNION ALL
SELECT  0 AS InExtCost, 10.123456789 As InTranQty   UNION ALL
SELECT  0 AS InExtCost,  0 As InTranQty       UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS InExtCost, 0 As InTranQty    UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS InExtCost, NULL As InTranQty    UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS InExtCost, NULL As InTranQty    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS InExtCost, 1 As InTranQty
```

In your expression I have added a conversion to double using Cdbl function

```
=Code.Divide(   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(Sum(Cdbl(Fields!InExtCost.Value), "ClassDesc"), 5)
, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(Sum(Cdbl(Fields!InTranQty.Value), "ClassDesc"),  First(Fields!DecimalsQuantity.Value, "RptParameter"))
)
```

Now that each parameter your are passing to the Divide function is double you can simplify it (or leave it as it is)

```
Public Function Divide(ByVal dividend As Double, ByVal divisor As Double) As Double
   If     divisor = 0 Then
      Return 0
   Else
      Return dividend / divisor
   End If
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've found another way that uses IIF and got the same result as yours, the problem is that the Grand Total has 14 decimals instead of 5, is that suppose to happen? I've tried to make the result 5 decimals with FormatNumber and it seems to have errors saving.

Comment: Ah i figured out by changing the format in the properties of the textbox

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to work at 5 decimal places, it's best to leave the values in their original state and then format them in the textbox properties as you have done for the total. That way you retain all the precision. If you ever exported the report to excel, the original, more precise value will be exported even though it will be formatted to 5 places. So, I would remove the 5 decimal place limit in your expression